# Как настроить Log4Net, что бы было определенное кол-во логов?

Tags: c#, .net, логирование, log4net

Сейчас имеется такая конфигурация:

```
 <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <target value="Console.Error"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout"/>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs\Log-%date{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.log"/>
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="15000000KB"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="3"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

По сути, на каждый запуск программы создается свежий лог.

Однако, хоть и указано, что нужно хранить 3 лога, то логи все равно копятся больше 3.

Можно ли это пофиксить или нужно ручками чистить?

Comment: проблема в том, что при каждом запуске l4Net начинает с нуля писать. оно не знает о твоих уже двух архивных логов.  Может при инициализации l4Net ты добавишь удаление архивных логов ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема связана, очевидно, с тем, что у Вас имена файлов лога основаны на шаблоне с датой. Причём формат даты такой, что ограничение на количество файлов лога будет иметь значение только в пределах 1 секунды. Проще говоря, логи будут чиститься сами только если их количество будет превышать 3 файла в секунду и удаляться будут именно те, которые были записаны в эту секунду первыми. Смотрим [документацию](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.MaxSizeRollBackups.html):

> The maximum applies to **each** time based group of files and **not** the total.

Возможное решение (на уровне патча) есть [тут](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-27), сам не пробовал.

---

Рекомендовал бы поэкспериментировать с этим и попробовать изменить шаблон имени файла, ограничив, например, 1 днём. Таким образом, если в течении дня будет записано более 3 файлов - должно произойти усечение.